# Detect button click on Webview of React Native

Tags: react-native, webview

I am developing a React Native app. It is a very simple app. I just have to load a website on a webview, which is perfectly done. but my client wants something which I am not sure how to do.

There are some social media buttons on the website. like facebook, twitter etc. so my client wants me to open social media app while user tap on them. suppose user tapped on facebook button then the facebook app will load.

[image: Image for UI]

I badly need to know the solution. please help me. thanks in advance.

Comment: I think the concept you are looking for is [linking](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking.html). This library is a place to start: [react-native-app-link](https://github.com/fiber-god/react-native-app-link)

Answer (score 0):

Make use of [onMessage](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/webview.html#onmessage).

Code is untested but you should get the gist of what it's trying to achieve.

Webpage:

```
function facebookClick() {
    window.postMessage("Facebook button done got clicked");
}

var _fb_button = document.getElementById("your-facebook-button");
_fb_button.addEventListener("click", facebookClick, false);
```

WebView:

```
[...]
import { Linking } from 'react-native';
[...]
    <WebView
         onMessage={(event) => {
                        let message = event.nativeEvent.data;
                        if(message.includes("Facebook button done got clicked")) 
                            Linking.openURL('fb://page/PAGE_ID');
                    }}
[...]
```

You'll have to check out the current protocol's details of each of the social apps you're trying to open via deeplink. Once you've done that, you can further improve your code with [Linking.canOpenURL](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking.html#canopenurl)

Comment: i have no access to the webpage. so i can't add or remove from there.

Comment: @SaddafAfrin you can make use of injectJavascript to add the event into the html.

Comment: Is it possible to pass multiple values in  window.postMessage ?